# Cocos2d-x V3. How to determine admob banner height for different screen sizes?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, admob, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

The rectangle is positioned at y=102.

```
auto spr    = Sprite::create("images/interface/wideBtnBlack.png");
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
spr->setColor(Color3B::GREEN);
spr->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + 200, origin.y + 102));
spr->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO);
```

How can I make sure that the rectangle is placed right above the banner for all devices?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can set Banner Size According to Device. and then By Doing Simple Math You can Achieve what you are Trying to Get. or Use Admob Delegate Method to Get Banner Height.

```
Banner.Height + (Object.Height/2) = Position Exactly Above Banner.
```